# Show presentation slide in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, presentation

In an upcoming project I'd like to guide my audience through a presentation as well as showing some code in RStudio. To use the screen space optimally I'd like to show the presentation (a PDF) in the environment area of RStudio (top right corner). This way I could display some code on the left, the presentation in the top right and plots in the bottom right corner.

Does an RStudio plugin exist to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using R Markdown for the your presentation? I think you are planning to provide a coding demonstration. In a Markdown file, you can have the plots generate under each chunk and the PDF generate in the Viewer pane with Gear Icon > Preview in Viewer Pane.

Comment: @SusanSwitzer Do you have an example of such a Markdown file? I'm currently not planning to use markdown, but could switch if it's convincing enough.

Answer (score 0):

File > New File > R Markdown
New your file
Select PDF from the Default Output format
A minimal working example will be populated with the Motor Trend Cars data frame.

Run any single 'Chunk' with the tiny green arrow to make your plots generate under the code

[image: sample]

Additional viewing options in preview pane

[image: options]

Comment: Thank you. I'm still not sure how this works. I opened a new R Markdown file. And can generate a PDF using knitr. This pdf will open in a new window though. What will I see during the presentation? The markdown file and the pdf?

Comment: Did you set the Preview in Viewer Pane preference?

Comment: Yes. I did set the Preview in Viewer Pane preference. What does this change? Do I have to _render_ the Markdown file or something?

Comment: Yes, when you render the Markdown file with knit, the pdf should display in your viewer pane

Comment: This does work. But now I don't think that Rmd is practicable in my situation. I need slides for the presentation (not a continuous scroll).